# Math.Round with Mid point Rounding

Tags: c#, rounding

This sample code is producing unexpected result

```
decimal s = 463.815M;
decimal a = Math.Round(s, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal b = Math.Round(s, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

decimal t = 4.685M;
decimal c = Math.Round(t, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal d = Math.Round(t, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.WriteLine(d);

Console.Read();
```

It [produces](http://ideone.com/fSVflI)

```
463.82
463.82
4.69
4.68
```

I was expecting **a** and **c** to have incremented by 1 which c did but to my surprise a didn't. Can anyone explain the reason for this please?

[**update**]

a and c are expected to have same results as:

- a has .81**5** and c also has .68**5** i.e. **5** at the end.
- a and c both are using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Comment: Those results are not consistent with your code. `a` and `b` are both `463.82`, which is expected.

Comment: The results are correct. Just check them out carefully.

Comment: You say that `a` didn't increment by `1` like `c` did.  But it seems to me like it did increment just the way you were expecting (from `463.815` up to `463.82`).  So I don't understand your question.

Comment: @yogi re. your update; they *do* yield the 'same' result: they both round "away from zero", i.e. upward for positive numbers. `.815` becomes `.82` and `.685` becomes `.69`, just like expected. Read the docs on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected result, because `0.815` fraction is rounded up to `0.82`. The same exact thing happens when you round to even, because `2` is even.

The result would be different if you used `0.825` as a fraction:

```
decimal s = 463.825M;
decimal a = Math.Round(s, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
decimal b = Math.Round(s, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Now the code [prints](http://ideone.com/VgmUgP)

```
463.83
463.82
```

to illustrate the difference between `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` and `MidpointRounding.ToEven`.